# Tensorflow and Caffe running on local machines over ssh

Tags: ssh, cuda, tensorflow, caffe, nvidia

I'm trying to implement a system that it uses two CNNs, one for human detection and another one for pose estimation. The first one feeds the second with the bounding boxes and then for every detected human I get as output a predicted pose. The problem is that the implementation of the first network is in Caffe and the second in Tensorflow so I cannot use the single gpu on my machine to run both networks (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2210). So I was thinking if it is possible to run one of the two networks on a gpu in my local netwrok (over ssh maybe?), do you know if that's possible or if there is a framework that can something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You could run the first network on the GPU, and then you'd have to somehow transmit the produced data to another computer with another GPU (or just CPU if you want to do that). You could have your first network save the results to a file, and then write a script that transmits the file (could use scp) to the other computer.